# Menu link not work properly

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hyperlink, menu

I have problem with menu link. I use # in link. Using CMS - Wordpress. When i click on link mytournament i get only twiching. Other links works well.
Check here:http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
    <div class="menu-mainmenu-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-82">
                <a href="http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com/#home_slider">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-139">
                <a href="http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com/#mytournaments">My Tournaments</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-81">
                <a href="http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com/#event-list">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-88">
                <a href="http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com/#gallery">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-80">
                <a href="http://fdsfd.5gbfree.com/#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the link is `#mytouranments` but the section you are trying to link to is `id="myt"`.

Change the link to `#myt` and it works.

[image]